# Associated model returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-associations

Basically here is the problem. I am using EF and have 3 entities which are associated.
When a user tries to login they are directed to a userprofile view and from there they click a link to purchase card, the user enters PIN for the purchase to happen. So Im passing the user model to the new directed page but once I try to access the associated model (ex. User.Card.Status) it returns null for the object card.

Model Diagram: http://snag.gy/Z4UuD.jpg

index controller and userprofile controller: http://snag.gy/i9STW.jpg

Comment: Do you have lazy loading for your `Cart` navigation in the `User model`?

Comment: No I dont! how should i enable it?

Answer (score 0):

In your `User` model, mark your `Card` navigation as `virtual` to enable lazy loading:

```
public virtual Card Card {get;set;}
```

Or you can use Include to explicitly load the `Cart` model when you query for `User` objects, example:

```
db.Users.Include("Card").Where(u => u.Username == username);
```